# Checking if a blob exists in Azure Blob storage (php)

Tags: php, azure-blob-storage

Simple question; how do you check if a blob exists using PHP in Azure blob storage using the file name? I can't seem to find it in the API.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for those using PHP SDK v4.10

http://phpazure.codeplex.com/

```
$storageClient = $this->azure->get_blob_storage();

                    //check if blob exists

        $exists = $storageClient->blobExists(<container name>, <blob name>);
```

Go into the blob.php inside the SDK folder to see a complete list of API functions.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this today and this was the top search result so wanted to give my solution here which uses the prefix option to find only blobs which match the name I'm looking for.

You will need to include `use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\ListBlobsOptions;` as well.

```
function blobExists($name)
{
    global $blobClient, $blobContainer;

    $listBlobsOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
    $listBlobsOptions->setPrefix($name);
    $result = $blobClient->listBlobs($blobContainer, $listBlobsOptions);
    return count($result->getBlobs());
}
```

Comment: is there a way that I can target specific blobs? Instead of getting all 'SMITH' returns, can I just get a matching return for `SMITHRA`?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question can't you just pass `SMITHRA` to the function, i.e. `blobExists('SMITHRA')`?

Comment: I got it to work using this method, `$listBlobsOptions->setPrefix($name . '.jpg');` - The only way it worked was to add in the picture extension afterwards, but works beautifully, thank you! If I didn't have the extension, I would get all returns with SMITHRA, like SMITHRAC, SMITHRAZ, etc.. because `listBolbs` returns all blobs, not just one.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention you wanted to look for a specific file extension! Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP SDK for Azure.

```
/ Create blob REST proxy.
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

// Get blob.
$blob = $blobRestProxy->getBlob("mycontainer", "myblob");
if ($blob) {
   //blob exists
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this works with the new SDK, but if you are using v4, which I am see my answer for another way to do it.

Comment: this does not work. if the blob does not exist, it will throw an error "BlobNotFound"

Comment: errors can't be thrown, only Exceptions. so feel free to edit any updated SDK functionality to `try {} catch (Exception)`

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that `getBlob` receives whole `blobe`. For existence test is better

```
$blobService = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService(.);
$blobService->getBlobMetadata('', $blobPath);
```

According to Fiddler it calls only HEAD method.

I have

```
"name": "microsoft/azure-storage-blob",
"version": "1.5.4",
```